# How does DNS resolution work on iOS devices when VPN's are enabled?

Tags: ios, vpn, dns

I have a WireGuard VPN configured on my iPhone. There is a DNS server running on the machine at the other end of the VPN tunnel. This DNS server has records for `example.net` but no other domains. (For the purposes of this question, assume that `example.net` has no public DNS records.)

If I do not set the "DNS servers" configuration in the WireGuard app, I obviously cannot resolve the internal records for `example.net` and DNS continues to work for public records on, e.g., `example.com`.

If I do set the "DNS servers" configuration to point to the machine at the other end of the tunnel, I can now resolve internal records of `example.net`, as is expected. However, I can also still resolve `example.com` and all other public DNS records on the iPhone.

What is happening here? What is the fallback logic for the DNS resolver in iOS? If I do the analogous configuration on a Mac, only DNS records that the DNS server on the remote machine will resolve.

(There is no problem here: I'm happy that I can have "split" DNS without extra configuration, but I'm curious how it works.)

Comment: This is entirely dependent on how WireGuard passes the DNS configuration to the system: they can tell the system to use split DNS (like you have on iOS) or they can tell the system to forward all DNS requests to your DNS (like you have on macOS). So it's a question for the WireGuard people, how they set it in your case. (I'm a dev working on macOS and iOS VPN solutions; the crucial part may be [adding or leaving out an empty string in a setting](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/nednssettings/1406537-matchdomains) or whether the connection becomes the default route).

Comment: Bottom line: depends on WireGuard and on your specific configuration.